# javamail returning smtp as transport, instead of smtps

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, smtps

I set the mail.transport property to smtps, beside the very basic information for connecting to a smtps server:

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
    p.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    p.put("mail.smtps.auth", true);

    Session s = Session.getDefaultInstance(p,new Authenticator(){/*authenticator impl.*/});

    MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(s); /*then i set the subject, then the body... */
    mm.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, "myfakeaddress@gmail.com");
```

And now, i try to send my message. I want to try the static method; using the instance method `sendMessage` it works fine. Here it is:

```
    Transport.send(mm);
```

**It tries to connect to a smtp server, instead of a smtps server**. Stepping inside the implementation of javamail (btw, my version is 1.4.5) i've discovered that the method that fails is:

```
 transport = s.getTransport(addresses[0]);
```

because it returns an `SMTPTransport` instead of `SMTPSSLTransport`; this even if i've set the `mail.transport.protocol` property to smtps as you can see in the second line of code. 
Is my procedure buggy anywhere or it isn't possible to send smtps mails via `Transport.send` static method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515410/javamail-smtps-imaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Transport.send(msg)` is looking up the protocol(s) associated with the *recipients* of your email, for each [type](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Address.html#getType--) of recipient.

All your recipients are `InternetAddress`es, which [have the type `rfc822`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#getType--)

Here are three ways to set JavaMail to use smtps protocol for rfc822 addresses:

1. Add the line `rfc822=smtps` in the property files `javamail.address.map` or `javamail.default.address.map` (as described in [the `Session` javadoc](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Session.html))
2. Call [`s.setProtocolForAddress("rfc822", "smtps")`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Session.html#setProtocolForAddress-java.lang.String-java.lang.String)` on your instantiated session (requires JavaMail 1.4 or later)
3. Set the property `mail.transport.protocol.rfc822` to `smtps` when instantiating your session (requires JavaMail 1.4.3 or later)

Answer (score 2):

[Bill Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040885/bill-shannon) (current maintainer of JavaMail) suggests in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419660/315306)

> Get rid of all the socket factory properties; if you're using a
> reasonably recent version of JavaMail you don't need them. See the
> JavaMail FAQ for how to configure JavaMail to access Gmail. You'll
> also find debugging tips there if it still doesn't work.
>
> Also, change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance.

Here is the relevant code from the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail)

```java
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String username = "user";
String password = "passwd";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
// set the message content here

Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
try {
    t.connect(host, username, password);
    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
} finally {
    t.close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use an instance of Properties if you're not passing it to any other method?